# Using accumulate function with second to last value as .init argument

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rolling-computation, accumulate

I have recently come across an interesting question of calculating a vector values using its penultimate value  as `.init` argument plus an additional vector's current value. Here is the sample data set:

```
set.seed(13)
dt <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), time = rep(1:5, 2), ret = rnorm(10)/100)
dt$ind <- if_else(dt$time == 1, 120, if_else(dt$time == 2, 125, as.numeric(NA)))

   id time          ret ind
1   a    1  0.005543269 120
2   a    2 -0.002802719 125
3   a    3  0.017751634  NA
4   a    4  0.001873201  NA
5   a    5  0.011425261  NA
6   b    1  0.004155261 120
7   b    2  0.012295066 125
8   b    3  0.002366797  NA
9   b    4 -0.003653828  NA
10  b    5  0.011051443  NA
```

What I would like to calculate is:

> ind_{t} = ind_{t-2}*(1+ret_{t})

I tried the following code. Since `.init` is of no use here I tried the nullify the original `.init` and created a virtual `.init` but unfortunately it won't drag the newly created values (from third row downward) into calculation:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ind = c(120, accumulate(3:n(), .init = 125, 
                                 ~ .x * 1/.x * ind[.y - 2] * (1 + ret[.y]))))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
   id     time      ret   ind
   <chr> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         1  0.00554  120 
 2 a         2 -0.00280  125 
 3 a         3  0.0178   122.
 4 a         4  0.00187  125.
 5 a         5  0.0114    NA 
 6 b         1  0.00416  120 
 7 b         2  0.0123   125 
 8 b         3  0.00237  120.
 9 b         4 -0.00365  125.
10 b         5  0.0111    NA
```

I was wondering if there was a tweak I could make to this code and make it work completely.
I would appreciate your help greatly in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a state vector consisting of the current value of ind and the prior value of ind.  That way the prior state contains the second prior value of ind.  We encode that into complex values with the real part equal to ind and the imaginary part equal to the prior value of ind.  At the end we take the real part.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = c(ind[1],
                    Re(accumulate(.x = tail(ret, -2), 
                                  .f = ~ Im(.x) * (1 + .y) + Re(.x) * 1i,
                                  .init = ind[2] + ind[1] * 1i)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   id     time      ret   ind result
   <chr> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 a         1  0.00554   120   120 
 2 a         2 -0.00280   125   125 
 3 a         3  0.0178     NA   122.
 4 a         4  0.00187    NA   125.
 5 a         5  0.0114     NA   124.
 6 b         1  0.00416   120   120 
 7 b         2  0.0123    125   125 
 8 b         3  0.00237    NA   120.
 9 b         4 -0.00365    NA   125.
10 b         5  0.0111     NA   122.
```

### Variation

This variation eliminates the complex numbers and uses a vector of 2 elements in place of each complex number with the first number corresponding to the real part in the prior solution and the second number of each pair corresponding to the imaginary part.  This could be extended to cases where we need more than 2 numbers per state and where the dependence involves all of the last N values but for the question here there is the downside of the extra line of code to extract the result from the list of pairs of numbers which is more involved than using Re in the prior solution.

```
dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = c(ind[1],
                    accumulate(.x = tail(ret, -2), 
                               .f = ~ c(.x[2] * (1 + .y), .x[1]),
                               .init = ind[2:1])),
         result = map_dbl(result, first)) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Check

We check that the results above are correct.  Alternately this could be used as a straight forward solution.

```
calc <- function(ind, ret) {
  for(i in seq(3, length(ret))) ind[i] <- ind[i-2] * (1 + ret[i])
  ind
}

dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = calc(ind, ret)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   id     time      ret   ind result
   <chr> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 a         1  0.00554   120   120 
 2 a         2 -0.00280   125   125 
 3 a         3  0.0178     NA   122.
 4 a         4  0.00187    NA   125.
 5 a         5  0.0114     NA   124.
 6 b         1  0.00416   120   120 
 7 b         2  0.0123    125   125 
 8 b         3  0.00237    NA   120.
 9 b         4 -0.00365    NA   125.
10 b         5  0.0111     NA   122.
```

Comment: This is super brilliant, I'm just in awe how fantastic it has been formulated. So excited to learn such valuable point. I only have one question now that I understand how it works. In `accumulate2` all values of ret `.y` argument are present as we omit the first two but the values of `.x` argument are actually created in every iteration if I'm not mistaken or maybe I am missing something here. Would you please explain how it is? Thanks indeed.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.  I have revised it eliminating the accumulate2 and reducing it down to an accumulate.

Comment: Yes I noticed you used a three argument function but the `Ind` was not used in computation. Thank you very much I am so glad you are here and we could learn these brilliant techniques from you, this is certainly a lifetime opportunity.

Comment: Have added a Variation section and updated a number of times with simplifications.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. The second solution is even more simple. However, the first one was also clear for me as it made me watch some videos about complex numbers and review some old materials. I really appreciate your kindness and generosity. It has been a great learning day for me.

Comment: Complex numbers may be less familiar but are part of the base of R and I don't think that simply using them makes a solution less simple although in this case possibly a bit more hackish. Overall I think the first solution is simpler and certainly is more compact  but the second is better for extending to more general situations including N past values and dependence on all N and not just the one N ago.  The solution in the Check section is actually the simplest if we remove the requirement to use accumulate.

Comment: I understand you are quite. Since I never used them so far, that was the case for me. But I have become more interested to learn about other use cases of complex numbers in various solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it by creating dummy groups for each sequence, so that it can be done for any number of 'N'.  Demonstrating it on a new elaborated data

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     grp = c("a","a","a","a",
                             "a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b",
                             "b","b","b","b"),
                    rate = c(0.082322056,
                             0.098491104,0.07294593,0.08741672,0.030179747,
                             0.061389031,0.011232314,0.08553277,0.091272669,
                             0.031577847,0.024039791,0.091719552,0.032540636,
                             0.020411727,0.094521716,0.081729178,0.066429708,
                             0.04985793),
                     ind = c(11000L,12000L,
                             13000L,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,10000L,13000L,12000L,
                             NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
      )
df
#>    grp       rate   ind
#> 1    a 0.08232206 11000
#> 2    a 0.09849110 12000
#> 3    a 0.07294593 13000
#> 4    a 0.08741672    NA
#> 5    a 0.03017975    NA
#> 6    a 0.06138903    NA
#> 7    a 0.01123231    NA
#> 8    a 0.08553277    NA
#> 9    a 0.09127267    NA
#> 10   b 0.03157785 10000
#> 11   b 0.02403979 13000
#> 12   b 0.09171955 12000
#> 13   b 0.03254064    NA
#> 14   b 0.02041173    NA
#> 15   b 0.09452172    NA
#> 16   b 0.08172918    NA
#> 17   b 0.06642971    NA
#> 18   b 0.04985793    NA

library(tidyverse)
N = 3

df %>% group_by(grp) %>%
  group_by(d = row_number() %% N, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ind = accumulate(rate[-1] + 1, .init = ind[1], ~ .x * .y))
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#> # Groups:   grp, d [6]
#>    grp     rate    ind     d
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a     0.0823 11000      1
#>  2 a     0.0985 12000      2
#>  3 a     0.0729 13000      0
#>  4 a     0.0874 11962.     1
#>  5 a     0.0302 12362.     2
#>  6 a     0.0614 13798.     0
#>  7 a     0.0112 12096.     1
#>  8 a     0.0855 13420.     2
#>  9 a     0.0913 15057.     0
#> 10 b     0.0316 10000      1
#> 11 b     0.0240 13000      2
#> 12 b     0.0917 12000      0
#> 13 b     0.0325 10325.     1
#> 14 b     0.0204 13265.     2
#> 15 b     0.0945 13134.     0
#> 16 b     0.0817 11169.     1
#> 17 b     0.0664 14147.     2
#> 18 b     0.0499 13789.     0
```

---

Alternate answer in `dplyr` (using your own data modified a bit only)

```r
set.seed(13)
dt <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), time = rep(1:5, 2), ret = rnorm(10)/100)
dt$ind <- ifelse(dt$time == 1, 12000, ifelse(dt$time == 2, 12500, as.numeric(NA)))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

dt %>% group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(d= row_number() %% 2, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ind = cumprod(1 + duplicated(id) * ret)* ind[1])
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, d [4]
#>    id     time      ret    ind     d
#>    <chr> <int>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a         1  0.00554 12000      1
#>  2 a         2 -0.00280 12500      0
#>  3 a         3  0.0178  12213.     1
#>  4 a         4  0.00187 12523.     0
#>  5 a         5  0.0114  12353.     1
#>  6 b         1  0.00416 12000      0
#>  7 b         2  0.0123  12500      1
#>  8 b         3  0.00237 12028.     0
#>  9 b         4 -0.00365 12454.     1
#> 10 b         5  0.0111  12161.     0
```